# "Imported content is empty." error when scraping with ImportXML in GSheets

Tags: xpath, web-scraping, google-sheets

I need to scrape images' source URLs from a directory's linked web pages to columns into a Google Sheet.

I think using `IMPORTXML` function would be the easiest solution, but I get the *#N/A "Imported content is empty."* error every time.

I have tried to use [this extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/xpath-finder/ihnknokegkbpmofmafnkoadfjkhlogph/related?hl=en) as well to define XPath, but still the same error.

The page's source code, where image source URL is:

```
<div class="centerer" id="rbt-gallery-img-1">
  <i class="spinner">
    <span></span>
  </i>
  <img data-lazy="//i.example.com/01.jpg" border="0"/>
</div>
```

So I want to get "i.example.com/01.jpg" value to B2, followed by further images' URLs to adjacent cells.

The function I used is:

```
=IMPORTXML(A2,"//img[@class='centerer']/@data-lazy")
```

I tried using spinner instead of centerer, with the same result.

Comment: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/126329/186471

Answer (score 0):

You can get the string `i.example.com/01.jpg` with the following XPath-1.0 expression:

```
substring-after(//div[@class='centerer']/img/@data-lazy,'//')
```

If you don't need to remove the leading `//`, you can only use

```
//div[@class='centerer']/img/@data-lazy
```

---

So, in the first case, the Google-Sheets expression could be

```
=IMPORTXML(A2,"substring-after(//div[@class='centerer']/img/@data-lazy,'//')")
```

and in the second it could be

```
=IMPORTXML(A2,"//div[@class='centerer']/img/@data-lazy")
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer!
Unfortunately, both functions return error:
The first: Imported Xml cannot be parsed
Second: Imported content is empty